# Why would the .NET JIT compiler decide to not inline or optimize away calls to empty static methods that have no side effects?

Tags: c#, clr, compiler-optimization

I think I'm observing the .NET JIT compiler not inlining or optimizing away calls to empty static methods that have no side effects, which is a bit surprising given some bespoken online resources.

My environment is Visual Studio 2013 on x64, Windows 8.1, .NET Framework 4.5.

Given this simple test program (https://ideone.com/2BRCpC)

```
class Program
{
    static void EmptyBody()
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        EmptyBody();
    }
}
```

A release build with optimizations of the above program produces the following MSIL for `Main` and `EmptyBody`:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  call       void Program::EmptyBody()
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main

.method private hidebysig static void  EmptyBody() cil managed
{
  // Code size       1 (0x1)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ret
} // end of method Program::EmptyBody
```

It's not surprising that the MSIL contains a call from `Main` to `EmptyBody`, since the C# compiler isn't expected to inline or optimize away calls like that. However, I thought that the JIT compiler would then inline or optimize away that call. But that doesn't seem to happen.

If I run the above program and break into the debugger in `Main`, the generated assembly is this:

```
00572621  mov         ebp,esp  
00572623  cmp         dword ptr ds:[4320B84h],0  
0057262A  je          00572631  
0057262C  call        73E6AF20  
00572631  call        dword ptr ds:[4321578h]
```

The instruction pointer is immediately set to the last line at 00572631, which is the call to `EmptyBody`. Stepping into `EmptyBody`, the generated assembly is found to be

```
00BD2651  mov         ebp,esp  
00BD2653  cmp         dword ptr ds:[4B00B84h],0  
00BD265A  je          00BD2661  
00BD265C  call        73E6AF20  
00BD2661  nop  
00BD2662  pop         ebp  
00BD2663  ret
```

The instruction pointer is immediately set to the `nop` line at 00BD2661, which doesn't do anything, and I cannot guess why it's generated in the first place.

Given that the two assembly snippets above share the same 4-instruction header, I assume that's just the regular method entry boiler plate where the stack and such is set up. I'm keen to learn to know what these recurring instructions would do, though:

```
00BD2653  cmp         dword ptr ds:[4B00B84h],0  
00BD265A  je          00BD2661  
00BD265C  call        73E6AF20
```

**Anyhow, the main question is: Why does the JIT compiler produce assembly that calls the empty-bodied static method `EmptyBody`?**

Comment: I am not an expert on C#. but observing a system changes it ;) You might see the code emitted entirely for the benefit of your debugger.

Comment: True. Then I'm curious to know how one can ever know if a call has been optimized away or not , which some of the "bespoken online resources" claim to have observed :-)

Comment: @JohannGerell turn off the debug flag and compile for release mode, then attach a debugger at run time, this will ensure you are debugging the actual code. I don't believe the JIT will monitor the debugger to see if its attached later on and make changes to the asm based on that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After digging a bit further, it turns out I can answer this question myself. As explained at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/02/20/535807.aspx , observing the disassembly of an optimized release build under the debugger will by default affect the JIT compiler.

Unchecking these

- ‘Suppress JIT optimization on module load’
- ‘Enable Just My Code’

under VS > Tools > Debugging > General, will show the "real" JIT compilation result, which for the call to `EmptyBody` in my `Main` above is this:

```
004C2620  ret
```

Meaning that the call to `EmptyBody` is completely removed, which is what was expected and the world is still a happy and somewhat predictable place to live in :)

Comment: The `nop` is a dead giveaway that this is happening. If you see those, you know what to do :)

Comment: The linked blog article says the same: there should be no `nop` if you've followed the advice correctly.