# Can a static class extension be inlined?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, jit

I have a tendency (throw back to c++ days) to add inlining hints to small methods, for example:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void Add(this IProject @this, IComponent component)
{
    @this.Components.Add(component);
}
```

I was wondering whether a static class extension-methods could be inlined in the first place?

Comment: Do you really need those micro-optimizations? It's not C++ days anymore, you can trust your compiler. Moreover inlining hints should normally be placed on larger methods which you think the compiler won't inline. But the outcome is probably in the nanoseconds anyway.

Comment: Isn't it better to get rid of that habbit at the first place?

Comment: The question is still perfectly valid even if we disagree with the use-case of it.

Comment: Probably not. But the attribute is there, the functionality is there. Its a legitimate question.

Comment: Why would static methods be excempt from inlining?

Comment: Did not say it was not a legit question. Only that you should really rethink your scenario, in a maintenance point of view. You're probably wasting more time writing one inlining attribute than it will ever save in your program's entire life.

Comment: It's become a bad habit to question developers' judgement, especially when it comes about optimization. There are lots of cases where the slightest optimization makes a difference. C# was not made with the same mindset as C++ but that's precisely the reason to want to optimize wherever possible. Among other areas C# is now used in gaming industry where operations/calls could get as high as tens of thousands and not per second but at 60, even 90 frames per second.  
Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Static methods can be inlined. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892766/why-would-the-net-jit-compiler-decide-to-not-inline-or-optimize-away-calls-to-e) for information on how to check if a method is being inlined. Extension methods are no different from normal static methods; in IL they are just decorated with a `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`, so they will be treated the same by the JIT.